# Não Consigo abrir uma página pelo VSCode

Tags: html, css, html5, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Estou fazendo minha primeira página WEB conforme exercícios da faculdade, até ontem estava usando o *VSCode* normalmente, porém hoje estava eu fazendo alguns teste e quando fui executar, apareceu a página "localhost:8080" e não abriu a página do código *HTML*, tentei abrir o mesmo código que havia aberto antes e não deu certo.
Tentei ver a configuração e abre uma aba de "launch.json" com a configuração:

```
{
  // Use o IntelliSense para saber mais sobre os atributos possíveis.
  // Focalizar para exibir as descrições dos atributos existentes.
  // Para obter mais informações, acesse: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
  
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:8080",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Veja se o ajuda: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_launching-browsers

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Eu não sei como você estava fazendo pra executar antes... mas eu recomendo que você utilize uma extensão para executar os seus códigos, pessoalmente utilizo a Live Server feito por Ritwick Dey (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer), para instalar é bem simples é só ir na aba de extensões e utilizar a barra de pesquisa, ai é só clicar no botão de instalar.
Essa extensão vai adicionar um botão na barra inferior é só clicar em "Go Live" e o site vai abrir.

mas caso você não queira:

```
{
    "name": "Launch NomeDoProjeto",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "chrome",
    "file": "${workspaceFolder}/index.html",
    "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

PS: Caso tenha curiosidade pesquise sobre o "XAMPP", ele é um programa para criar projetos locais. vai ser lá que você vai criar um localhost.

Comment: Bom dia meu amigo, nesse exemplo que vc me passou deu certo, porém quando tento abrir outro código, abre o anterior, antes toda vez que eu fazia um código diferente, era só apertar f5 que abria no navegador sem problema, agora dessa forma terei que mudar o nome (no "file") toda vez que fazer um código novo?